# mongoProc failed to check updates : Connection timed out

Tags: mongodb

I installed mongodb 2.6 on windows successfully

I am trying to connect to mongoProc.I installed it from Mongodb university 
but its giving error as
failed to check updates.Reason : Connection timed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you are behind a firewall (at least this was my case).
In order to resolve it modify ~/.config/mongoProc/user_settings.json (for Linux) and set your proxy settings; for example if the proxy is on http://192.168.56.254:

```
{
 " proxy": {
    "host": "192.168.56.254",
    "port": "80",
    "type": "http"
  }
}
```

For Windows you should modify the C:/Users//AppData/Local/mongoProc/user_settings.json or C:/ProgramData/mongoProc/user_settings.json

For more information and proxy configurations you can check [this link](https://university.mongodb.com/mongoproc).

Comment: took a few extra gyrations. My proxy points to a pac file which has to be opened to see the real proxy address. Regardless once I had it this was the perfect solution.

Answer (score -1):

It generally means that mongoProc is behind a local or network firewall or a network proxy server.

to test (from a command (terminal) prompt)

ping google.com

ping mongoproc.mongodb.com

telnet google.com 443

telnet mongoproc.mongodb.com 443

This will start to advise you as per which issue.

Comment: To Check if you can access MongoProc , you need to check the following command.